# A Proof about the Oscillation of a Function on Compact Interval

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, proof-verification

> Let $f$ be a bounded function on a compact interval $J$, and let $I(c,r)$ denote
>   the open interval centered at $c$ of radius $r > 0$. Let $\text{osc}(f,c,r) = \sup |f(x)-f(y)|$, where the supremum is taken over all $x,y \in J\cap I(c,r),$ and define the oscillation of $f$ at $c$ by $\text{osc}(f,c)=\lim_{r \rightarrow 0}\text{osc}(f,c,r)$. Clearly, $f$ is continuous at $c\in J$ if and only if $\text{osc}(f,c)=0.$
>
> For every $\varepsilon >0,$ the set of points $c\in J$ such that $\text{osc} (f,c)\geq \varepsilon$ is compact.

I have two proofs below that I think do the trick.

$\textbf{First Proof}$: First note that the set in question, call it $\mathcal{C}$ is bounded, so it suffices by Heine-Borel to prove that its complement is open. We will prove that every point of $\mathcal{C}^\complement$ is an interior point. So let $c \in \mathcal{C}^\complement$ be arbitrary but fixed.

By definition, we can choose $\delta>0$ small enough so that $\text{osc}(f,c,\delta) = \sup |f(x)-f(y)|<\varepsilon$, where the supremum is taken over all $x,y\in\mathcal{B}(c,\delta).$ Then for any $a\in\mathcal{B}(c,\delta),a\ne c,$ we can choose $p>0$ with $p<\delta$ small enough, so that we have $\text{osc}(f,a,p) = \sup |f(x)-f(y)|<\varepsilon.$ Therefore $\lim_{r \rightarrow 0}\text{osc}(f,a,r)<\varepsilon.$ It follows that $c\in \mathcal{C}^{\complement}$ is an interior point. Since $c$ was arbitrary, we see that $\mathcal{C}^{\complement}$ open, so that $\mathcal{C}$ is closed, and since it is also bounded, it is compact.

$\textbf{Second Proof}$: We prove that $\mathcal{C}$ is closed by showing it contains all its limit points. So let $c$ be a limit point of $\mathcal{C}.$ Then for any $\delta>0$, we have that $(\mathcal{B}(c,\delta)-\{ c \})\cap\mathcal{C}\ne\emptyset$. This means that $\text{osc}(f,c)=\lim_{r \rightarrow 0}\text{osc}(f,c,r)\geq\varepsilon,$ since we can choose $\delta>0$ so small that for some $a\in(\mathcal{B}(c,\delta)-\{ c \})$ we have that $\text{osc}(f,a,\delta) = \sup |f(x)-f(y)|\geq\varepsilon,$ and hence $\text{osc}(f,c,p) = \sup |f(x)-f(y)|\geq\varepsilon,$ for some small enough $p>0$ with $p<\delta$. Since $\delta\geq 0$ was arbitrary, the result about the oscillation at $c$ follows. Therefore $c\in \mathcal{C},$ so the latter is closed.

---

Is the above proof correct? Any feedback is welcomed and much appreciated, be it about the style or the argument, or both.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Both the proof appear to be right but the first one looks simpler and neater.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The proofs are more or less acceptable. The first proof has some minor flaws.

If you care about making a complete and precise argument, then in the first proof you state but do not justify why $\text{osc}(f,a,p) < \epsilon.$

The argument would be as follows.  Given $\beta$ such that $\text{osc}(f,c) < \beta < \epsilon$ there exists $\delta$ such that $\text{osc}(f,c,\delta) \leqslant \beta.$   Since $\mathcal{B}(a,p) \subset \mathcal{B}(c,\delta)$ it follows that for all $x,y \in \mathcal{B}(a,p) \cap J$,

$$|f(x) - f(y)| \leqslant \sup_{u,v \in \mathcal{B}(c,\delta)\cap J}|f(u) - f(v)| = \text{osc}(f,c) \leqslant \beta < \epsilon$$

Thus,

$$\text{osc}(f,a,p) =\sup_{x,y \in \mathcal{B}(c,\delta)\cap J}|f(u) - f(v)| \leqslant \beta < \epsilon, $$

and

$$\text{osc}(f,a) = \inf_{r} \,\text{osc}(f,a,r) \leqslant \beta < \epsilon,$$

which implies that $\mathcal{B}(c,\delta) \cap J \subset \mathcal{C}^c$.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer. If you don't mind me asking, would you consider the second proof complete enough, or should I add more details?

Comment: @GabyAlfonso: You're welcome.  It is just some minor nitpicking.  Let me look at the second proof more closely.

Comment: @GabyAlfonso: The second proof is OK.  Perhaps stated more concisely, if $c$ is a limit point then there exists $a \in \mathcal{B}(a,p) \subset \mathcal{B}(c,\delta)$ such that $a \in \mathcal{C} \setminus \{c\}$.  Hence, $\epsilon \leqslant \text{osc}(f,a,p) \leqslant \text{osc}(f,c,\delta)$ .  This leads to $\epsilon \leqslant \text{osc}(f,c)$.

Comment: Thank you for your valuable feedback and help.